# Neural Network and RC Boat

Tags: neural-network, robotics

Just a theory before i start making anything
I was always interested in NN and did some smaller console projects with them but this time i would like to use them in real life.

Let's assume i have a big pool at home - i have a small RC boat that is equipped with very sensitive and accurate GPS and a tiny computer inside with some SD card module to load/save Neural Network data.

The boat has 1x Servo (to control the turn) and 1x Motor to move forward.

I would like the boat to learn itself to navigate to a single waypoint as first, and then use that network to navigate between multiple waypoints.

I am thinking of the following **inputs**:

- Distance to WPT
- Direction to WPT

**Outputs**:

- Motor throttle
- Servo turn

In the training period, i can't figure out if i should use supervised approach (rc boat, i can control it at the start), or non supervised learning?

**Question**:

before i start digging in to the code i would rather like to ask pros for an advice.

1. a) Is it even possible to use NN in a project like this?
2. If yes, should i be doing supervised learning (showing the network
   how to navigate to a single wpt so many times that the network
   learns it and then use this network to navigate autonomously to
   other wpt?)
3. Inputs / Outputs - anything else is needed to allow this to work?

Many thanks for any input into this.

**Update with a proof of concept project**

Because i couldn't get an answer on this i tried learning the network to cruise to a next waypoint by using two inputs:

1. Current Boat Angle  [0,360]
2. Angle to next Waypoint [0,360]

And one Output

1. Rudder angle [-1,1]

And here are the results, it didn't take too much time to learn.

- Yellow box - the trainer boat
- Blue box the neural network driven boat

https://youtu.be/_FDWSBYj7WM

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the right task for a neural network. It sounds like a task to apply reinforcement learning such as Q-Learning.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-learning

If you also would like to use ANNs you could use them as function approximators. I think Google did that with their Alpha Go bot.

Comment: So i've used NN to find out if they are applicable for a job like this. The inputs were current boat angle and destination angle, the output is LEFT/RIGHT rudder control. Results as per below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ry3EG3Fv4nw

It's a simple test so don't expect anything mindblowing however it seems like it can do the task pretty well.


Updated version of the NN:
https://youtu.be/_FDWSBYj7WM

Comment: Well! That's quite cool! Thanks for that. Did you check out reinforcement learning?

Comment: Hey Bastian, not yet - seems like simple RNN does the job for now. Let me check that in reality first and get back here with some updates. Thanks for the Reinforcement learning pinpoint, if i will have not satisfying results with RNN will go for Reinforcement to see..

Comment: Of course! For me, reinforcement learning was the technique to apply for such tasks: http://maciejjaskowski.github.io/2016/03/09/space-invaders.html
But you showed me that it's quite possible to solve this by an RNN. Did you used gate nodes in your RNN or is it just a basic one?

Comment: So i used basic backpropagation neural network here, nothing special - just simple as it is. 2 Inputs, 4 Hidden, 1 Output (as stated in updated description). Well if that works on the simulator then maybe it's not needed to overcomplicate things.. I will be trying to add couple of additional inputs here - starting with throttle to see how it impacts the NN learning and effectiveness.

Comment: @Pees looks great. Can you share the code, what are u using for the simulation?

Comment: @mwweb, the whole code was written by myself (including gui/simulator/...) i'll try to find the code (maybe i still have it) and let u know